# Is there a zip function to create tuples with more than 2 elements?

Tags: swift

I just discovered the Swift `zip` function recently. It seems quite useful.

It takes 2 input arrays and creates an array of tuples out of pairs of values from each array.

Is there a variant of zip that takes an arbitrary number of arrays and outputs tuples with that same number of elements? It seems like there should be a way to do this.

Comment: I'm no expert at Swift but while you can create a function that takes a variable number of sequence parameters, how would you declare the return type to be a tuple of unknown size?

Comment: Good point. You can use generics to define the function to create tuples who's elements are the types of the input array elements, but I don't know of a way in Swift to define a tuple of variable size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `zip` for an arbitrary number of sequences isn't currently possible due to Swift's lack of variadic generics. This is discussed in [the Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#variadic-generics).

In the meanwhile, I wrote a `gyb` template for generating ZipSequences of custom arity. I've also pre-generated ZipSequences of arity `3...10` for your convenience. [It's available here.](https://github.com/amomchilov/ZipNsequence)

In action:

```
let integers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let strings = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let doubles = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

for (integer, string, double) in zip(integers, strings, doubles) {
    print("\(integer) \(string) \(double)")
}
```

Prints:

> 1 a 1.0
>
> 2 b 2.0
>
> 3 c 3.0
>
> 4 d 4.0
>
> 5 e 5.0

Comment: Thanks for the conclusive answer and the link to the Generics Manifesto.

Comment: You can write your own zip3 or such, based off the source: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Zip.swift

Comment: @Alexander i am getting error of `extra argument in call` i am doing exactly what you are doing, whats error in my code?

Comment: should i  import something or just add the sequecs

Comment: @iOSDeveloper You just copy the source file into your project. I haven't bothered to make it into a standalone library or framework, or anything like that

Answer (score 20):

Bear in mind, you can nest one `zip` inside another, and then unpack it with a nested tuple:

```
let integers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let strings = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let doubles = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

for (integer, (string, double)) in zip(integers, zip(strings, doubles)) {
    print("\(integer) \(string) \(double)")
}
```

Not quite as elegant as having a `zip` for arbitrary n-tuples, but it gets the job done.

Comment: You are a genius.

Comment: i am getting error of `extra argument in call` i am doing exactly what you are doing, whats error in my code?

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer - no need to fight Swift's standard library for only one nested tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested `zip` approach as in some of the previous answers, and use `map` to flatten the result:

```
let combined = zip(integers, zip(strings, doubles)).map { ( $0.0, $0.1.0, $0.1.1 ) }
```

It yields an array of tuples, each with three elements. Looks a bit ugly but as long as it works… It does work as long as the number of arrays to zip is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the output as an array instead of a tuple then here is a solution.
This is utilizing the heterogeneous array of type [Any] in Swift 5.7

```
func zipAny(_ data: [[Any]])->[[Any]]{
    let count = data.first!.count
    let initArray = Array(repeating: [], count: count)
    let reduced : [[Any]] = data.reduce(initArray, {
        Array(zip($0,$1)).map({
            var arrayCopied : [Any] = $0.0
            arrayCopied.append( $0.1 )
            return arrayCopied
        })
    })
    return reduced
}

let inputArray = [[1,2,3],["a","b","c"]]
let outputArray = zipAny(inputArray)

print(outputArray)
// [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```