# Increment array index Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, pffile

I have some objects in parse server, I am retrieving the objects successfully. The issue I am having is that I have a PFFile object storing images and it’s **Optional**. Whenever the PFFile array doesn’t have the same number of values as the other arrays populating my tableview, the program crashes because the index is out of range. I am unable able to increment the PFFile array index with the indexes of the other arrays to populate my TableView. How can I increment the index of the PFFIle array to have the same index count as the other arrays? Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source. This is an object oriented language. Use a custom struct or class.

Comment: @vadian, thanks for your reply. I am getting the data from parse, so that's the only way I know of to retrieve data from parse. My issue is trying to figure out how to increment the an array with PFFile objects

Comment: @IamWayne If you get your data from your source as separate arrays, I'd iterate through them at data collection time and merge them into a single array of a custom struct as soon as you get them. Dealing with multiple parallel arrays like this is just going to lead to a lot of headaches.

Comment: Without code, I've got no idea what your data looks like, but here's an option you might be able to consider. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40540683/4475605